# Verbes de perception : influence du choix entre une subordonnée et l'infinitif sur la simultanéité des évènements

Tags: verbes, infinitif, subordonnées, verbes-de-perception

Page 8 dans *Advanced French Grammar*, V. Mazet affirme ceci :

> A construction with {**qui + conjugated verb**} can be used instead of the infinitive after a verb of perception. However, there's a slight difference in meaning when you use that construction. As the English translations with progressive forms indicate, {**a relative clause + conjugated verb**} denotes complete simultaneity. The infinitive construction doesn't necessarily indicate this and is therefore more versatile.
>
> 1. Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens qui lui font du mal. = Sometimes he notices the people (who were) making him unwell/bad.
> 2. Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens lui faire du mal.

Je ne pige pas comment l'infinitif a un sens différent de la tournure ***qui* + verbe conjugué**. D'après moi, le sens de la première phrase équivaut à celui de la deuxième.

---

Une annexe grâce à Stéphane Gimenez : Veuillez consulter aussi [Infinitive or present participle in a sentence's object](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/infinitive-or-present-participle-in-a-sentences-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mazet confond complètement deux constructions distinctes, ce qui change, ce n'est pas la construction relative, mais plutôt **la nature du complément d'objet direct**.

Dans le cas d'une relative avec *qui*, le complément, ce sont les personnes. Ils les a vues, c'est tout, et *qui* n'introduit rien d'autre qu'une relative déterminative définissant les gens qui ont été vus.

Dans le cas d'une construction infinitive, c'est une phrase entière, par l'intermédiaire de son infinitif, qui est devenue le complément, c'est **la situation elle-même** que l'on observe, si on ajoute une traduction, la différence devient particulièrement claire (je corrige aussi la traduction de la première phrase ne serait-ce que parce qu'un présent anglais est une bien mauvaise traduction de ce passé composé):

1. *Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens qui lui font du mal.* = Sometimes he's seen **the people that hurt him.**
2. *Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens lui faire du mal.* = Sometimes he's seen **the people hurting him.** (si on voulait que la traduction laisse encore moins d'ambigüité, on pourrait employer *witnessed*)

Comment: Bonne explication. C'est un peu le même phénomène qu'[ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/infinitive-or-present-participle-in-a-sentences-object). Par contre en anglais je tique sur le present prefect pour une répétition, un présent simple me parait mieux (ou un past perfect, mais ça ne colle plus à la phrase originale).

Comment: @Circeus: Je vous remercie bien.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de me le faire savoir. J'ai relié cette question-là ici.

Answer (score 4):

> Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens qui lui font du mal.

Cette phrase signifie qu'il a vu les gens qui, habituellement, font du mal, mais pas nécessairement à cet instant où il les aperçoit.

> Quelquefois il a aperçu les gens lui faire du mal.

Cette phrase signifie qu'il a vu les gens en train de lui faire du mal [*au moment même où il les voit*]

Comment: Je vous remercie bien.